# Not using a safe call operator

Tags: kotlin

Suppose we have a Nullable string assigned as null
But somewhere down the code we give it a value 
I call str. Length

it says we can’t call the method without the safe call operator(?.), I mean since we already know it’s no more null as we have it a value , can’t I just call the length method

Comment: you can soround the method call with a check if is not null

Comment: You can also use scoping functions like `possibleNullString.let { it -> // The string was not null } ?: //The string was null`

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that the value is not null you can call

```
value!!.length
```

or use default value, for example:

```
value?.length ?: 0 // default value will be 0
value?.length ?: return // return if value is null
```